# How to change the size of a shape based on Cell width

Tags: vba, excel

How to change the size of a shape based on Cell width

For example, my cell B1 having Width: 14:00 (103 Pixels) and C1 having Width: 16:00 (117 Pixels)
The shape placed inside that Rage should change its size to 220 Pixels.

And also whenever the width change it should adjust with its size! so there should be a provision to find the cell width.

The code I have will help me to center it

```
Sub Set_shape()

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Select 'get the object
With Selection
    .Left = Range("B1:C1").Left + (Range("B1:C1").Width - Selection.Width) / 2
    .Top = Range("B1:C1").Top + (Range("B1:C1").Height - Selection.Height) / 2
End With

End Sub
```

Is it possible? and if yes please help me to modify this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are `14:00` and `16:00`?

Comment: ya it will be 220 sorry

Comment: Why not try edit the `.Width` and `.Height` fields of `Selection` to resize the way you are editing the `.Left` etc to reposition it?

Comment: 14:00 and 16:00 are width of the cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the idea is to have the shape exactly as the given range, then this is how to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetShape()

    Dim rect1           As Shape
    Dim rngToCheck      As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rect1 = .Shapes("Rectangle 1")
        Set rngToCheck = .Range("B1:C1")
    End With

    With rect1
        .Left = rngToCheck.Left
        .Top = rngToCheck.Top
        .Width = rngToCheck.Width
        .Height = rngToCheck.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

This is what you would get:

[image]

The good part is that if you change the size of the cells, the shape changes as well by default:

[image]

---

If you want to put some border around the shape, it is possible to play a bit like this:

```
Sub SetShape()

    Dim rect1           As Shape
    Dim rngToCheck      As Range
    Dim borderSize      As Double

    borderSize = 0.9

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rect1 = .Shapes("Rectangle 1")
        Set rngToCheck = .Range("B1:C1")
    End With

    With rect1
        .Width = rngToCheck.Width * borderSize
        .Height = rngToCheck.Height * borderSize
        .Left = rngToCheck.Left + (.Width / 2) * (1 - borderSize)
        .Top = rngToCheck.Top + (.Height / 2) * (1 - borderSize)
    End With

End Sub
```

In this case the border is given as a `borderSize` and this is the result:
[image]

Comment: I would guess the auto-resize with the cell sizes is just a property to set on `rect1` as well

Comment: Thank you @ Vityata, is there a provision to keep it little smaller than the size of the column so that I will get a nice border

Comment: `With rect1
        .Left = rngToCheck.Left - 7
        .Top = rngToCheck.Top - 7
        .Width = rngToCheck.Width - 7
        .Height = rngToCheck.Height - 7
    End With
    
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Select 'get the object
With Selection
.Left = Range("B1:C1").Left + (Range("B1:C1").Width - Selection.Width) / 2
.Top = Range("B1:C1").Top + (Range("B1:C1").Height - Selection.Height) / 2
End With`    this worked for me, thank you once again @Vityata